# Get in undefined. Angular Factory & Ionic Framework Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a factory in the background. I struggled with an injector error so I put the factory in the `app.js` rather than the `services.js`. Doing this fixed the injector problem but now when I call `factory.get` from `app.js`, I get "not a function".

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers','ngStorage','ngCordova'])

var myService = app.factory('myService', function($localStorage, $scope, $http) {

    var items = $http.get("url + $localStorageVariable").then(function(resp) {

      if (resp) { 
        return resp['data.items'];// This will produce promise, not array so can't call directly
        console.log("Factory success");
        } else {
          console.error('ERR', err);
        }
      });

      return {
        getAll: function() {
            return items;
        }
      }
});


 //later in app.js
         myService.getAll().then(function(items){ 
          console.log("Debug. This line in service call") //this doesnt log.
          console.log(items)
         });
```

**ERROR**:

> app.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: myService.getAll is not a function

**EDIT:**

What I have now is this:

```
    var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers','ngStorage','ngCordova'])



app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    } 
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }


  (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('starter', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .factory('myService', myService);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, myService) {
    function getSuccess(response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
    }

    function getError(response) {
      console.log('error');
    }

    myService.getAll()
      .then(getSuccess)
      .catch(getError);
  }

  function myService($http) {
    var factory = {
      getAll: getAll
    };

    return factory;

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get("url");//triple checked, not the isssue
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: you have defined the service, but you didn't instantiate it here.  Factories are designed to be instantiated by the Dependency Injection process during module instantiation, but you aren't really showing which module you are trying to use this in.  Just FYI, you can only use Providers in `app.config` or `app.run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you didn't *inject* your `factory` into your `controller`. Also, there's a mistake in how your `factory` was written. Check the example below:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('starter', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .factory('myService', myService);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, myService) {
    function getSuccess(response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
    }

    function getError(response) {
      console.log('error');
    }

    myService.getAll()
      .then(getSuccess)
      .catch(getError);
  }

  function myService($http) {
    var factory = {
      getAll: getAll
    };

    return factory;

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get('url');
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: If im trying to use it from app.js how do i inject it? What controlller? I am trying to get this to run in the background when the app is 'sleeping'

Comment: See it above: `MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService']; function MainCtrl($scope, myService) {`

Comment: no i keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined` ill update my question with ur code suggestions

Comment: @MrKale, please don't copy the whole suggestion in your question or my answer will make no sense, since it's the same thing. Well, about the problem.. you still have some mistakes, I just tested it *again* and it really works.. See the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7GXmxVG4lay59d25eiSM?p=preview) and check the comments also..

Comment: thank you for organizzing the plunker. i created a fork that has the rest of my app.js that is causing issues. not working yet :/

Comment: thanks for the help.. I marked it solved. if u could take a look at the new problem Id appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841903/config-issues-with-factories-in-app-js-stateprovider